# Почему значение равно null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, юнит-тесты, moq, xunit

Вопрос в следующем, есть следующий фрагмент unit-теста

```
// Arrange
            var mock1 = new Mock<IRtbService>();
            mock1
                .Setup(a => a.GetAuctionResult(rtb_partners, auctionModel))
                .ReturnsAsync("VAST");
```

По сути он должен вернуть строку VAST, но при отладке он возращает null, с чем может быть связанна данная "особенность"?

P.S
Вот полностью метод`GetAuctionResult():` 
`public Task GetAuctionResult(IEnumerable rtb_partners, AuctionModel auctionModel();`

Скриншот null при отладке теста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите фреймворк тестирования. Я правильно понимаю, что вы mock1 передаёте в конструктор контроллера, а то прямо говоря не очевидно из приведённого кода, так это или нет.

Comment: Фреймворк - XUnit + Moq, да вы все правильно понимаете

Comment: Вы указываете возврат VAST для определённого набора входных данных. Для любых данных надо что-то типа: `.Setup(a => a.GetAuctionResult(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))` типы подставите сами, из кода не видно.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы правы, только что нашел это в документации к Moq

Comment: @AK можно было ответом

Comment: Уступаю топикстартеру, пусть сам напишет.